# Haskell Tree - Show instance

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, ghci

I am learning haskell and i want to print all nodes in tree (depends on height on tree, where height = 0 => leafs). And i thinking, that I create a good function, but i have a problem with show function.

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)  deriving (Show)  

tree4 = Node 1 (Node 2 Empty (Node 0 Empty Empty)) (Node 4 Empty Empty)
tree5 = Empty

heightTree::Tree a -> Integer
heightTree Empty = 0
heightTree (Node x l r) =  1 + max (heightTree l ) (heightTree r)

treeLev::Tree a -> Integer -> [a]
treeLev Empty a = []
treeLev (Node x l r ) a = if a == heightTree l || a == heightTree r  then [x] else treeLev l (a-1) ++ treeLev r (a-1)
```

and when I'm using

```
*Main> treeLev tree4

<interactive>:105:1:
    No instance for (Show (Integer -> [Integer]))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (Integer -> [Integer]))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
*Main>
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong :)?

Comment: `treeLev` receives two arguments. So `treeLev tree4` is a function. You can't print functions.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you give isn't telling you that you can't print the tree, it is telling you that you are trying to print out a function, and it can't do that.

You didn't show us the line with the `show` or `print`, so we can't see how to fix it, but that is what the message tell me.

Comment: I don't have any line with show or with print. I just compile with ghci and test function in console.

Comment: @neptyd The line that is printing is the one you're trying to evaluate in GHCi.  Whenever you execute an expression in GHCi, there's an implicit `print` in front of it, since it'd be pretty useless as an interactive environment otherwise.  What you need to do is execute something like `treeLev tree4 x`, where `x` is whatever `Integer` is appropriate.  Then you'll be evaluating it to a value of type `[a]`, which can be printed.  Functions can't be printed in Haskell because that's basically an impossible task for all sorts of technical reasons.